# Sql dynamic columns with different queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008. And i have some very special task and i really hope you guys can help me with this and that it is technical possible...

Every person has its lecture and can choose a waiting line for that he can register in a waiting list.
The waiting lines must be dynamic. so that for every congress i can say i have 2 lines or 3 or 4 and so on, depending on the needs.

The overview i need is one column for each waiting line with the person in order of the 'lecture start date' in relation to the current datetime. All lectures whose start is in the past should be ignored.

I have created a sqlfiddle for that **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/120ef**

If the fiddle is changed or corrupted here is the structure, data and selects.
http://filex02.mcon-mannheim.de/public.php?service=files&t=da4e6fc71cdf30804cb5f51b843ce368

For every lane i can use a query like this ( You can use this for fiddle)

So for all waiting lines i need 4 queries like this

```
SELECT p.Firstname+' '+p.Lastname as Lane1 --, * 
FROM WaitingLine    wLine 
    JOIN WaitingList wList ON wLine.WaitingLaneID = wList.WaitingLineID 
    JOIN Person p ON wList.PersonID = p.PersonID 
    JOIN Lecture l ON wList.LectureID = l.LectureID 
WHERE wLine.Name = 'Lane1'  AND l.StartDate > GETDATE() 
                                AND wList.Called = 0 
ORDER BY l.StartDate
ASC;
```

> 

```
SELECT p.Firstname+' '+p.Lastname as Lane2 --, * 
FROM WaitingLine  wLine 
    JOIN WaitingList wList ON wLine.WaitingLineID =  wList.WaitingLineID 
    JOIN Person p ON wList.PersonID = p.PersonID 
    JOIN Lecture l ON wList.LectureID = l.LectureID 
WHERE wLine.Name = 'Lane2'  AND l.StartDate > GETDATE() 
                            AND wList.Called = 0 
ORDER BY l.StartDate ASC;

SELECT p.Firstname+' '+p.Lastname as Lane3 --, * 
FROM WaitingLine wLine 
    JOIN WaitingList wList ON wLine.WaitingLineID = wList.WaitingLineID 
    JOIN Person p ON wList.PersonID = p.PersonID 
    JOIN Lecture l ON wList.LectureID = l.LectureID 
WHERE wLine.Name = 'Lane3' AND l.StartDate > GETDATE() 
                           AND wList.Called = 0 
ORDER BY l.StartDate ASC;

SELECT p.Firstname+' '+p.Lastname as Lane4 --, * 
FROM WaitingLine wLine 
    JOIN WaitingList wList ON wLine.WaitingLineID = wList.WaitingLineID 
    JOIN Person p ON wList.PersonID = p.PersonID 
    JOIN Lecture l ON wList.LectureID = l.LectureID 
WHERE wLine.Name = 'Lane4' AND l.StartDate > GETDATE() 
                           AND wList.Called = 0 
ORDER BY l.StartDate  ASC;
```

The Result of this query you can see here:

[image]

What i need would be only one single statement that results like this:

[image]

**Please note**, that no lane with content should start with NULL. All names need to be ordered by the start/beginning date of their lecture and the output should start in the first row of each column

Here are the tables that i use:

Table: **WaitingLine**

[image]

Table: **WaitingList**

[image]

Table: **Person**

http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/194/u67b.png

Table: **Lecture**

http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/7520/1tap.png

**THANKS**

Comment: I don't get your question? I see your table, but I don't see what your desired result should be.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have edited the question to clarify what i mean. I also added a sqlfiddle with test data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to get the results with dynamic columns, then you would need to revert to dynamic query creation. Please try the query below:

**Query**

```
Declare @Values as nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
Select @values = COALESCE(@Values + ',', '') + name FROM 
      (select distinct Name from   WaitingLine) as t order by Name

 Select @query = 'SELECT  * ' +' from (SELECT   wline.Name, FirstName+Lastname as who,
 Row_number() over (partition by wline.Name order by l.startdate) as rowX
 FROM WaitingLine    wLine 
 Left outer JOIN WaitingList wList ON wLine.WaitingLineID = wList.WaitingLineID 
 left outer JOIN Person p ON wList.PersonID = p.PersonID 
 left outer join Lecture l ON wList.LectureID = l.LectureID 
 WHERE   (l.StartDate > GETDATE() or l.StartDate is null)
                            AND (wList.Called = 0 or wList.Called is null) ) as t

        pivot 
        (
            max(who)
            for name in ( '+  @values + ')
        ) as p'

execute (@query)
```

**Results**

```
  rowX Lane1     Lane2       Lane3      Lane4
  1    BruceLee  MarcusReis  JohnSmith  NULL
  2    NULL      ChuckNorris JohnDoe    NULL
  3    NULL      BruceLee    SilentBob  NULL
  4    NULL      NULL        BruceLee   NULL
```

It will give you the desired result plus one extra column; hope that does not create problems to you. The Use of OR in the WHERE statement was to make sure you get the Lane4 records (no records) included - but in the end, you can remove the condition - without any consequence - it was more for me to check what is going on, so it is more or less almost the same query as yours. You might consider making a View for example, and then pivoting it - it works too, and will make the whole solution more compact.

Comment: Just to prevent errors it is better to use the replace-method for empty spaces.

Comment: Or better encapsulate with square bracket :: Select @values = COALESCE(@Values + ',', '') + '['+name+']' FROM

Answer (score 2):

The query below does what you ask for, but there may well be a more elegant and scalable implementation.
I haven't tested it on any other dataset than the one you supplied and I would advise testing on realistic data.
I have left superfluous fields in the sub-queries for you to examine the data but they should be removed once you are happy. They are :- wLine.Name AS Lane and l.StartDate.
That being said, Enjoy!

**Query:**

```
SELECT  Lane1, Lane2, Lane3, Lane4
FROM 
(
    SELECT p.Firstname+' '+p.Lastname Lane1, wLine.Name AS Lane, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY l.StartDate) AS rn, l.StartDate
    FROM WaitingLine wLine
    JOIN WaitingList wList ON wLine.WaitingLaneID = wList.WaitingLineID
    JOIN Person p ON wList.PersonID = p.PersonID
    JOIN Lecture l ON wList.LectureID = l.LectureID
    WHERE l.StartDate > GETDATE() 
    AND wList.Called = 0
    AND wLine.Name = 'Lane1'
) Lane1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT p.Firstname+' '+p.Lastname Lane2, wLine.Name AS Lane, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY l.StartDate) AS rn, l.StartDate
    FROM WaitingLine wLine
    JOIN WaitingList wList ON wLine.WaitingLaneID = wList.WaitingLineID
    JOIN Person p ON wList.PersonID = p.PersonID
    JOIN Lecture l ON wList.LectureID = l.LectureID
    WHERE l.StartDate > GETDATE() 
    AND wList.Called = 0
    AND wLine.Name = 'Lane2'
) Lane2
ON Lane1.rn = Lane2.rn
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT p.Firstname+' '+p.Lastname Lane3, wLine.Name AS Lane, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY l.StartDate) AS rn, l.StartDate
    FROM WaitingLine wLine
    JOIN WaitingList wList ON wLine.WaitingLaneID = wList.WaitingLineID
    JOIN Person p ON wList.PersonID = p.PersonID
    JOIN Lecture l ON wList.LectureID = l.LectureID
    WHERE l.StartDate > GETDATE() 
    AND wList.Called = 0
    AND wLine.Name = 'Lane3'
) Lane3
ON (    Lane1.rn = Lane3.rn
    OR  Lane2.rn = Lane3.rn)
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT p.Firstname+' '+p.Lastname Lane4, wLine.Name AS Lane, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY l.StartDate) AS rn, l.StartDate
    FROM WaitingLine wLine
    JOIN WaitingList wList ON wLine.WaitingLaneID = wList.WaitingLineID
    JOIN Person p ON wList.PersonID = p.PersonID
    JOIN Lecture l ON wList.LectureID = l.LectureID
    WHERE l.StartDate > GETDATE() 
    AND wList.Called = 0
    AND wLine.Name = 'Lane4'
) Lane4
ON  (   Lane1.rn = Lane4.rn
    OR  Lane2.rn = Lane4.rn
    OR  Lane3.rn = Lane4.rn)
```

**Results:**

```
Lane1       Lane2           Lane3       Lane4
Bruce Lee   Marcus Reis     John Smith  NULL
NULL        Chuck Norris    John Doe    NULL
NULL        Bruce Lee       Silent Bob  NULL
NULL        NULL            Bruce Lee   NULL
```

As per Daniels answer below, to add the dynamic element you require you could try building it within another query then using `EXECUTE` or `sp_execute` to run it but remember that there are pro's and con's to this approach - I heartily recommend that you read this [article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).
Here's my take on the dynamic sql approach using `sp_executesql`:
**Query:**

```
    DECLARE @columns AS NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',', '') + name 
FROM  WaitingLine
ORDER BY Name
--SELECT @columns--

DECLARE @stmt AS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @params nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME
SET @startdate = GETDATE()
SET @params = N'@sd DATETIME'
SET @stmt = N'SELECT  '+@columns+' 
              FROM (SELECT wline.Name AS LaneName
                        , FirstName + '' '' + Lastname AS PersonFullName
                        , Row_number() over (partition by wline.Name order by l.startdate) AS rn
                    FROM WaitingLine    wLine 
                    LEFT JOIN WaitingList wList 
                        ON wLine.WaitingLaneID = wList.WaitingLineID 
                    LEFT JOIN Person p 
                        ON wList.PersonID = p.PersonID 
                    LEFT JOIN Lecture l 
                        ON wList.LectureID = l.LectureID 
                    WHERE   l.StartDate > @sd
                  AND wList.Called = 0) AS src
              PIVOT (MAX(PersonFullName) FOR LaneName IN ('+@columns+')) AS pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt, @params, @sd=@startdate
```

**Results:**

```
Lane1       Lane2           Lane3       Lane4
Bruce Lee   Marcus Reis     John Smith  NULL
NULL        Chuck Norris    John Doe    NULL
NULL        Bruce Lee       Silent Bob  NULL
NULL        NULL            Bruce Lee   NULL
```

Comment: Hi Mack, thanks for that solution. I am happy with it, the only thing i am missing is that this statement is static and not dynamic. The count of lanes can vary.